# JAVA : Point in polygon? How can I check if a user's location falls within a kml polygon?

Tags: java, maps, polygon, kml, point

I have .kml shape files which contain region polygons, what I want to do is to find out that specific marker or point lies inside a polygon. I want to do this in java. Any library to parse through .KML files ?

Answer (score 6):

The [JTS Topology Suite](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/locationtech.jts) is a good choice to correctly calculate geometric relationships in geospatial context. The KML can easily be parsed using an XML Parser or a Java library such as [JAK](https://github.com/micromata/javaapiforkml) or [GIScore](https://github.com/OpenSextant/giscore) in which you can access the coordinates of the features.

Here is snippet of Java code using JTS to test if a geospatial point is inside a polygon.

```
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.*;

// parse KML using JAK or another library
// ...
GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();
// create polygon
int numPoints = ...
Coordinate[] points = new Coordinate[numPoints];
// set points
points[0] = new Coordinate(...);
//...
LinearRing jtsRing = gf.createLinearRing(points);
Polygon poly = gf.createPolygon(jtsRing, null);

// now create point to test if contained inside polygon
Coordinate coord = new Coordinate(lon, lat);
Point pt = gf.createPoint(coord);
if (poly.contains(pt)) {
  // point is contained within bounds of polygon
  // do something here
}
```

The contains() geometry predicate is defined in the [JTS javadoc](http://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Geometry.html#contains(org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry)).

Comment: Is JTS still the best to perform this calculation? Or Spatial4j is now a better candidate?

Comment: Polygons in Spatial4J are supported by wrapping JTS's Geometry.

Comment: Ok thank you @JasonM1! I have another question : is the results would be always correct? I mean is it average correct or precisely correct? I have the feelings that there is a risk that results won't be good because geospatial maths seems to be very complicated.

Comment: If coordiantes of the points and polygon use the same reference coordinate system (e.g WGS84) then the math should be correct. If you require a high degree of accuracy then recommend to review the source code and/or the documenation for accuracy. If for example the length between the points in the polygon are large then that itself could introduce error.

Comment: The above code got me most of the way there.  A few notes:
1.  I needed to make sure the first and last point were identical to close the polygon or JTS threw an exception.
2.  My test point, which definitely was contained in my polygon was returning false for the `contains` check until I changed from a LinearRing object to a Polygon object.  Yes, I know LinearRing is a child class of Polygon.
3.  The maven library I needed to run the above code is called `jts-core`.  Another called `topology suite` did not work.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

To parse the KML data, here is a library (took me two seconds of googling): https://github.com/micromata/javaapiforkml

To check if a coordinate falls into a shape, either the library offers a method for that (didn't check that) - or, you could just create a Java AWT `Polygon` from the coordinates of a shape (just treat them as points on a 2D surface). `Polygon` offers a `contains(Point2D)` method.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html

Comment: If polygon wraps International dateline or poles then AWT Polygon won't always work. In those cases need a geospatial library such as [JTS Topology Suite](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html). See [contains](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry.html#contains(com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry)).

Comment: AWT shapes assume a flat surface.  Not a good idea for geodetic computations.